# Salesforce Lighting- Inline Edit -show text box on change value from custom dropdown

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have need to replicate opportunity object Lighting Inline Edit Page in order to to show a text box only when the value is selected in the picklist.

If we use `<Lighting:record form>` i can get the inline edit page 
but i cannot add the condition to display the text box when the value is selected from drop down. Please help me how to add condition for ob change of picklist value.

```
<lightning:recordForm
        recordId="0062v00001DmT9sAAF"

        objectApiName="Opportunity"
        layoutType="Full"
            columns="2"
        mode="view" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`<lightning:recordForm>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordForm/documentation) doesn't allow you to add custom functionality to the generated form. More generally, there isn't any Salesforce component that allows you to generate a standard view but also make changes to its inner workings.

You can completely rebuild the form using [`<lightning:recordEditForm>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/example), but you'll have to define the entire form in your component.

A more sustainable solution in my opinion would be a small custom component placed on the Lightning Record Page *alongside* the standard record detail component and providing only your custom functionality. You can configure the component to display conditionally on the specific record value you want with the built-in support in the Lightning App Builder.

Comment: Hi David thank you so much for your reply .. But is there any other way to show this. if we use recordEditForm this page is differ from Inline Edit page design. Because for various opportunity stages i am displaying different page layout. only for this page i have on change scenario  to show text box.

Comment: @Kalaivani There's no way to render a standard page and then reach in and make changes to it. You've got to either rebuild it with your customizations, or place your customizations separate and alongside it.

Comment: ok. Thank you..do have custom component code similar to this scenario. Since i tried searching for this. i am not get any example codi

Comment: @Kalaivani I suspect you're going to have to write the code here. I am not aware of any examples similar to your expectation.